# how to print 1.5Kv instead of 1500 V?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm making a calculator and the results that I'll get will be either very small or very big . So how can I change unites for a results which is 
where Vout is defined as a float.

```
Vout=1500;
self.myOutputValue.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f V",Vout];
```

this will print `1500.00 Volts`
what should I do to get it to print `1.5 KV`

```
self.myOutputValue.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%(  ????  ) KV",Vout];
```

Comment: self.myOutputValue.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f kV",Vout/1000];   ... no? either this, or I do not understand the question ... or if you want to have both, check with an if if vout is larger than 1000 before using the second version ...

Comment: yah that would be easy but I was wondering if there is somthing that will allow  you to specify how many decimals on the left ?

Comment: Numeric formats in `stringWithFormat` will, unless directed otherwise, "expand" to handle the size of the number.  Ie, you'll get "1.2", "12.3", "123.4" for 1.231, 12.312, 123.442 automatically with the `%.1f` format code.

Comment: And the proper unit is `k`, not `K`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you like the concept of using Engineering format (i.e. 100 increments up and down) there is a nice routine in C/ObjectiveC on github: [EngineeringNotationFormatter](https://github.com/dhoerl/EngineeringNotationFormatter). It will let you specify the number of significant digits to show, so if you have chosen three you will get 125K, 12.5K, or 1.25K. It also lets you increment the number by the smallest possible increment up or down (useful if you couple the class to say a rotating incrementer/decrementer).

Answer (score 2):

```
NSString *str = nil;
if (Vout >= 1000.0)
{
    str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f KV",Vout/1000.0];
}
else
{
    str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f V",Vout];
}
self.myOutputValue.text = str;
```

Comment: And if you need to handle more orders of magnitude, check out the logarithm function, eg. `log(1000) = 3`. Round the log to the immediately inferior multiple of 3, then you'll have your multiplier (3=K, 6=G, 9=T, ...)

Comment: thanks I knew that ,  I was wondering if there is something that will allow  you to specify how many decimals on the left ?

Comment: can you show me an example if I will use logs ? please